# Python cast character to operation

Tags: python

I'm writing a simple Python program for a projecteuler question, and it involves generating a search space over operations, ex:

```
8 = (4 * (1 + 3)) / 2
14 = 4 * (3 + 1 / 2)
19 = 4 * (2 + 3) − 1
36 = 3 * 4 * (2 + 1)
```

I'm storing possible operations in an array:

```
op = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
```

I was wondering if there's any way in Python to cast a character to an operation, so I could simply do something like:

```
for operation in op:
    num1 foo(operation) num2
```

Answer (score 8):

You could use the [`operator`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) module to get the functionality you're looking for. The `operator` module has "a  set of efficient functions corresponding to the intrinsic operators of Python":

```
>>> import operator as op
>>> ops = {"+": op.add, "-": op.sub, "/": op.div, "*": op.mul}
>>> num1, num2 = 3, 6
>>> for name, fn in ops.iteritems():
...     print "{} {} {} = {}".format(num1, name, num2, fn(num1, num2))
... 
3 + 6 = 9
3 * 6 = 18
3 - 6 = -3
3 / 6 = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

What do you think about:

```
In [1]: add = lambda x,y: x+y

In [2]: sub = lambda x,y: x-y

In [3]: mult = lambda x,y: x*y

In [4]: divs = lambda x,y: x/y

In [5]: ops = [add,sub,mult,divs]

In [6]: for op in ops:
   ...:     print op(1,2)
   ...:     
3
-1
2
0
```

**UPDATE**: after posting my answer I noticed @mdml 's answer - I think it's more elegant than mine TBH :)

Comment: sweet use of lambdas!!

Comment: @mdml's is a bit more concise, but yours does offer some good practice in first-order functions

Answer (score 1):

eval may help:

```
op = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
num1, num2 = 3, 6
for operation in op: 
    print eval("{} {} {}".format(num1, operation, num2))
```

*Gives:*

```
9
-3
18
0
```

Or can use an op table:

```
def add(x,y) : return x + y 
def sub(x,y) : return x - y 
def mul(x,y) : return x * y 
def div(x,y) : return x / y 

op = {'+' : add, '-': sub, '*' : mul, '/' : div }
num1, num2 = 3, 6
for operation in op.keys():
    print op[operation](num1, num2)
```

Answer (score -2):

No you cannot do that.

You would have to create functions that would do all of the operations that you require.